# Encoded character is used instead the correct one

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe, character-encoding

I have a little problem and I'm hopping that you can help me solve this annoying issue.

I need to use an iFrame in an administration panel to let users use the selection service, and in the HTML I have:

```
<iframe scrolling="yes" runat="server" title="Par Selection" id="iFrame"
    frameborder="0" enableviewstate="true" width="100%" height="490" />
```

in my code-behind file I have:

```
iFrame.Attributes.Add("src", String.Format(
            "https://www.parurval.se/urval/?username={0}&password={1}",
            parSettings.GetSettings(parSettings.SettingsType.PARSelection, parSettings.SectionType.Username),
            parSettings.GetSettings(parSettings.SettingsType.PARSelection, parSettings.SectionType.Password)));
```

The output is this:

```
<iframe id="tcMain_tabPARSelection_iFrame" scrolling="yes" title="Par Selection" 
   frameborder="0" width="100%" height="490" 
   src="https://www.parurval.se/urval/?username=myUsername&amp;password=myPassword">
</iframe>
```

Please **note** the **`&amp;`** instead **`&`** sign in the src address when passing username and password

How can I prevent this?

I tried with HttpUtility.Decode( myCompleteUrl ) but with the same achievement :(

*The worst thing is*, if the src code has only the address

```
... src="https://www.parurval.se/urval/" ...
```

I'm not able to input the user/pwd, I see the form and I can enter text, but it does nothing, it only refreshes the iframe inner page, doing this in a full window, works fine.

And in that administration panel I have a textbox to the user add the username and password in order that entering the Administration page, I will jump directly to the service in the iFrame so the user does not need to enter user/pwd to login every time, that is way I'm trying to add those values dynamically.

Any ideas?

**Added:**
If I put the correct URL address (with user and pwd) in the iFrame src attribute in the HTML side (not dynamically) all works fine :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The presense of the &amp; is actually correct there. Most browsers are forgiving enough not to choke on just seeing & there, but it's technically not correct.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that there is no problem. It's actually going to go to the correct URL (with the &amp; replaced with &) when the browser sends the request for the page for the iframe.

Comment: +1 Yully is correct. If you have a problem following the link it is not happening for the reason you think. Every browser in existence will see the attribute containing ‘&amp;’ and correctly put ‘&’ in the link.

Comment: I will forward this issue to the website owner then. Thnxs for the help

Answer (score 2):

“&” is a special character in HTML (more specifically in SGML), so encoding it is the correct thing to do. Yes, even in link URLs.

Comment: I know that :) but I need to show & in the HTML in order to separate the Query String parameters, any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You don’t understand. A URL like “.../urval/?username=a&amp;password=b” is _correct_. There’s no need to write invalid HTML, browsers can very well handle correct HTML. :)

Comment: I do... but this is not in a browser it is in a iFrame, and that behavior does not replicate if using an iFrame :) the endpoint does not know what's &amp; is. please try for your self.

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether it’s in a iframe. It’s HTML. You have to encode special characters like “&”. There’s not a real need for discussion. Also, if you experience problems I’m very sure it’s _not_ because “&” has been encoded.

Answer (score 1):

The [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#h-5.3.2) states:

> Authors should use "&amp;" (ASCII decimal 38) instead of "&" to avoid confusion with the beginning of a character reference (entity reference open delimiter). Authors should also use "&amp;" in attribute values since character references are allowed within [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-cdata) attribute values.

So encoding the `&` as `&amp;` is correct behavior since the interpretation of the `src` attribute value ([CDATA data type](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-cdata)) is described as:

> **CDATA** is a sequence of characters from the document character set and may include character entities. User agents should interpret attribute values as follows:
>
> - Replace character entities with characters,
> - Ignore line feeds,
> - Replace each carriage return or tab with a single space.

Otherwise `src` attribute values like `/foo?bar&sect=123` would be ambiguous as they can be interpreted either literally as `/foo?bar&sect=123` or (replacing the [`sect` entity](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html#h-24.2.1)) as `/foo?bar§=123`.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a case where you can take advantage of URL encoding to hide the &, bypassing XML encoding. & is U+0025, so you can encode it as %25: https://www.parurval.se/urval/?username={0}%25password={1}

Comment: was absurd first time I read, but, I had to try before I write something, did you tried this yourself?

Comment: Well, in my case I didn't have to escape &. In fact, i use this all the time at SO. THe MSDN URLs contain (VS8.5). Markdown syntax is [text](url) so it truncates the URL after VS(8.5). %28VS8.5%29 does work.

Comment: URL-encoding is the Wrong Thing here, you are making the ‘username’ value equal “username&password”.

Answer (score -3):

You should use

```
     HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(String.Format("https://www.parurval.se/urval/?username={0}&password={1}",            
parSettings.GetSettings(parSettings.SettingsType.PARSelection, parSettings.SectionType.Username),            
parSettings.GetSettings(parSettings.SettingsType.PARSelection, parSettings.SectionType.Password)));
```

Comment: Encode??? I'm guessing that you do not understood wither my problem or the Encode function